# Setting grails on ubuntu

Tags: grails

I have download grails 2.4.3 jar file and extracted in download folder.
My environment variables are as follows
    JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_25
    export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin 
    GRAILS_HOME=/home/sunny/Downloads/grails-2.4.3
export PATH=$PATH:$GRAILS_HOME/bin
so the main problem is i am able to create my grails program through ggts 3.6.4 ide but not able to create it from the terminal. Grails commands are not working in terminal.
Please help thanks.

Comment: please add the errors/traces/... you see.  "does not work" is no helpfull description of your problem.

Comment: there is no error coming in terminal. it shows nothing.

Comment: could you please be tad more specific? "shows nothing" does that mean, it jumps right back to the shell prompt or does it hang?  could it be timing out on a corporate firewall while it wants to download the deps?

Answer (score 0):

Have you give execution permission to grails command? In $GRAILS_HOME/bin you should do

```
chmod +x $GRAILS_HOME/bin/grails
```